# Compare a variety of class names with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a variety of class names for divs:

```
 box blue full

 box blue border purple

 box purple full

 box white purple border

 box purple border

 box purple full

 box blue border

 box white

 box white purple border
```

Each line is a separate div with it's particular class name. Other than the colors of blue, purple, and white, there could potentially be colors red, and green in there as well.

What I want to do is this:
I am looping through each div, and I want to check to make sure the div doesn't have any more than 1 color as a class name (except for white and another color)

So for example, "box blue border purple" is not ok, and I need to change that to the class name of "box white"

So basically, any div that has two colors needs to get changed to box white

If you want to see an example, 
I'm working on this: http://k.p2digital.net/ and if you click the red box, and then click on the box in the 3rd column at the top from the left, the box to the left of the red box you just created turns red... but sinces it's between another solid color box, that isn't it's own color, it should turn white.

I have a loop, that after you click runs and this is where I would check to make sure there are no boxes with the two different colors (meaning that box is in between two solid color boxes) and would need to be changed to white

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 36; i++){
        console.log($(".box[rel='"+[i]+"']").attr('class'));    
        class = $(".box[rel='"+[i]+"']").attr('class');



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
colArr=new Array('red','blue',...);
$('div.box').each(function(){
    var i,index;
    i=0;
    for(index in colArr){
        if($(this).hasClass(colArr[index])){
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    if(i>1){
        for(index in colArr){
            if($(this).hasClass(colArr[index])){
                $(this).removeClass(colArr[index]);
            }
        }
        $(this).addClass('white');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the 'brute force" way of doing things with a lot of extra comparisons.

Comment: @imsiso - I was just pointing out that this isn't a very efficient way to do it.  Efficiency may or may not matter in the actual application.  If there are N color values to test against and more than one matches, you are doing 2N `hasClass()` operations, each of which involves regular expression replace operations (internal to the `hasClass()` implementation). My alternative does no regex operations and if there are X actual class names on the object, mine does only X object lookups.

Comment: @imsiso - To explain, if there are 10 color names total to check against and three classes on the actual object, you would be doing 20 regex operations in `hasClass()` and my implementation would be doing 3 object lookups.

Comment: ok you are right your code (algorithm) is better than mine.(optimized).(-:.but I think if you could right your code using ready things.(i.e jQuery) it will be better.(-:

Answer (score 3):

If you want an efficient solution, you can count the colors in each item and if there are too many, set the class name to the non-color class names plus white:

```
// create map of all color names for fast lookup
var colors = {
    red: true,
    blue: true,
    purple: true,
    white: true
    // ...
};

$(".box").each(function() {
    // get each class name separately into an array
    var classes = this.className.split(" ");
    var colorCnt = 0, nonColors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (colors[classes[i]]) {
            // count the matching color
            ++colorCnt;
        } else {
            // save the non-color class name
            nonColors.push(classes[i]);
        }
    }
    // if too many colors, then set class name to all non-colors plus white
    if (colorCnt >= 2) {
        nonColors.push("white");
        this.className = nonColors.join(" ");
    }
});
```

Comment: @imsiso - because what you are suggesting doesn't look up an item in an array.  Arrays have numeric indexes, not string indexes.  You use an object to look up a key by string.

Comment: yes you are right I just read it very fast and write that very fast too. but btw you code is better when we have lots of extra colors but here this code will run by clicking(when a color is being added).and why you dont suggest thing jquery gives us?(because when we include it in page we had loaded it so why dont use it? and what about my comment on previose post?

Comment: @imsiso - I use jQuery when it's more efficient to write or execute.  I don't use it when plain javascript is better.  I used it for the selecttor and the `.each()` loop, but didn't see any way that it would help the rest of my code.   Doing lots of `hasClass()` comparisons didn't seem like the best approach to me.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
$('.box').attr('class', function() {
    var m = this.className.match(/blue|purple|white|red/g);
    if (m.length > 1) {
        return this.className.replace(RegExp(m.join('|'), 'g'), '') + ' white';
    }
});
```

For example for box with classes `box blue border purple`:

```
"box blue border purple".match(/blue|purple|white|red/g) // ["blue", "purple"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9U3JH/2/

Comment: A loop with `hasClass` would be more efficient (who cares), plus easier to read and extend (maybe). Just an idea.

Comment: This doesn't preserve non-color classes like `border`.